# DATASTAGE- SQL Server from datastage: load table with strange name

Tags: sql-server, datastage

I have a SQL Server table, whose name is like `Vers-xxx_yyy`.
As you can see, there is a character "-".

I don't know why this table was made so, but I have to load it from datastage job.
So when I run my job, I obtain error "table doesn't exist".
I use odbc stage.

Directly on SQL Server it is possible to use syntax `[Vers-xxx_yyy]`, but not in datastage.

This db already exists and it is used by other applications.

Is there a way to avoid/resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes over the table name. Also it is good practice not to use hyphen, instead you can use underscore

Comment: I am not the owner of DB, so I can't do anything. I found solution, using square brackets around table name and odbc stage with option upsert. Using option write, it gives error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using a backslash \ to escape the - character - `Vers\-xxx_yyy`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put the table name in this form on the ODBC Connector too: `[Vers-xxx_yyy]`

Another solution would be to inform the SQL to query this table: `SELECT * FROM [Vers-xxx_yyy]`